# Whether equality of two sections of an integral affine scheme can be check fiberwise?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

If $X\rightarrow S$ is a morphism between two integral affine schemes, and $a,b\in X(S)$ are two sections. Assume that $a$ and $b$ agree after base change to each geometric point of $S$, are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $k[t]_{(t)} \subset k[t,x]_{(t,x)}, a:x \mapsto t, b: x \mapsto t^2 $